# JFace TableViewerColumn cannot show border

Tags: swt, jface

I have created Table using JFace TableViewer in Eclipse RCP. Code is like this.

```java
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
composite.setBounds(0, 0, 248, 139);
TableColumnLayout tcl_composite = new TableColumnLayout();
composite.setLayout(tcl_composite);
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
TableColumn tblclmnDepartment = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
tcl_composite.setColumnData(tblclmnDepartment, new ColumnPixelData(150, true, true));
tblclmnDepartment.setText("Department");
tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new TableLabelProvider_1());
String data[] = {"A","D","S"};
tableViewer.setInput(data);

table = tableViewer.getTable();
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);
table.setRedraw(true);
.
.
class TableLabelProvider_1 extends StyledCellLabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {
return element.toString();}
@Override
public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
return null;
}
}
```

Howerever I cannot see border around cell in the table. I think Border color is white. I have changed the background color and It show me border.

Can you please tell me how to change  border color ?

Can you please help me out

Comment: So what do you get? I would expect this to give lines between columns and lines between rows or alternating row colors (depending on the platform).

Comment: I am using windows7 and I am surprized that it does not show lines.However I tried this table.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW)); and it show me border lines. I Think Border lines are white so Cannot be viewed. Can you please suggest how to change border line color